# QR Scanner Camera Preview stops and starts again and then shuts down when reads qr code

Tags: android, zxing, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I have implemented QR Scanner inside my app. I used Firebase MLKit as well as tried Zxing Scanner.

I start new activity where qr scanner runs. Once it detects valid qr code it finishes the scanner activity and send the result back to previous activity.

Everything works without any errors.

But there is small bug probably with Camera in android.

After getting valid qr code camera shuts off for a second then starts again and after a second or two shuts down and then activity gets finishes and return result to previous activity.

I have tried Camera, Camera2, Zxing Core, MLKit with all possible combinations. Everytime same thing occurs.

I also tried couple of Github Repos
MLKitQRScanner, KotlinFirebaseMLKitQRRealtimeDemo, QRCodeCameraX, QRScannerCameraX

This is using CameraX but I also tried the older camera apis in android with same result

I think the problem is with camera preview but I tried camera2 and cameraX api. both gives same output. So it is probably something in code.

ACTIVITY

```
var analyzerHandler: Handler? = null
var analysis: ImageAnalysis? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner_x)

    context = this

    Dexter.withActivity(this)
        .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                textureView.post {
                    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { textureView.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
                    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

                    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
                        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                        setTargetRotation(textureView.display.rotation)
                        setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
                    }.build()

                    val analysisConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
                        setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
                        val analyzerThread = HandlerThread("BarcodeFirebaseAnalyzer").apply { start() }
                        analyzerHandler = Handler(analyzerThread.looper)
                        setCallbackHandler(analyzerHandler!!)
                        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                        setTargetRotation(textureView.display.rotation)
                        setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
                    }.build()

                    val preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(previewConfig, textureView)
                    analysis = ImageAnalysis(analysisConfig)

                    val googlePlayServicesAvailable = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)
                    if (googlePlayServicesAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                        analysis!!.analyzer = BarcodeFirebaseAnalyzer { barcode ->
                            toAddAuth(barcode) //THIS RUNS ONCE VALID QR CODE IS THERE. ITS JUST INTENT TO SEND BACK THE RESULT FOR startActivityForResult
                        }
                    } else {
                        analysis!!.analyzer = BarcodeZxingAnalyzer { barcode ->
                            toAddAuth(barcode)
                        }
                    }

                    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this@ScannerX, preview, analysis)
                }
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?, token: PermissionToken?) {
                //
            }
        }).check()
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    textureView.postDelayed({
        textureView.systemUiVisibility = flagsFullscreen
    }, immersiveFlagTimeout)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    analyzerHandler?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    analyzerHandler?.looper?.quitSafely()
    analysis?.analyzer = null
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

I just need to close camera and activity once analyzer gets valid code

ALSO IF I PRESS BACK BUTTON ON SCANNER ACTIVITY CAMERA PREVIEW GOES OFF AND THEN TURN BACK ON AND HAVE TO PRESS THAT BACK BUTTON AGAIN TO FINISH THIS SCANNER ACTIVITY.

SO ITS NOT JUST BARCODE LISTENER. IT HAPPENS WITH BACK BUTTON AS WELL.

Comment: can you share the log file ?  I can send an example of qr scan if that's the only target you need.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/2gihc thanks for the reply

Comment: Yeah only QR Scan

Comment: Ok, I will instead create a gist of a QR Code. will share it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a gist of QR Code, let me know if this helps you

```
// QR Code - XZing
implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
```

[QR Code Gist File](https://gist.github.com/ralphgabrielle/2c3a5081ae4cbe615c615abfd59fad2f)

Don't forget to add the permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks it works. I am still looking for the mlkit solution though.

Comment: glad it works, yes the ML Kit is still worth the time though. Ill update the gist when I find the time to create an ML Kit version of it.

Comment: I am going to use qrcodereaderview since CameraX and MLKit seems buggy. CameraX is still in alpha so make sense. But it would be great if you add MLKit.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I dont know exactly what causing this issue but somehow this whole thing doesn't work inside an Activity .

CameraX.bindToLifecycle have some strange bug which messing up with Activity LifeCycle.

Implementing everything inside Fragment does solve the issue. Only thing is have to keep all Camera related stuff inside fragment. When its time to finish the activity and return scan results to previous activity better do it in Activity hosting the fragment.

Comment: how did you solve this problem? I am implementing zxing & camerax api but somehow not able to use both of them because whenever I am binding the image analyser to lifecycle, the preview vanishes.

Comment: As I said before everything works properly inside fragment. Somehow it was messing up inside activity. But camerax is already got an update already so the thing i faced probably solved by now or the things you are facing are new in the latest version of camerax. Let me know which version camerax you are working with. I will look into it once i get home.

Comment: `1.0.0-alpha06` is the camerax version

Comment: Hi @ShubhamAgrawal my current version of CameraX is 1.0.0-alpha04. I tried changing it to current alpha06 and it stopped working. This library is still in alpha so it is expected to be broken sometimes. I can confirm that alpha04 perfectly works right now.

Comment: If using alpha04 solves your problem then well and good or you can start your thread and explaing your problem in detail with some code snippets. I might be able to help you. If you do start new thread then let me know